# undefined reference to `cv::Stitcher::createDefault(bool)'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to stitch images using `opencv` in `c++`, and when the program is compiled, its throwing errors for

`Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();`

> undefined reference to `cv::Stitcher::createDefault(bool)'

and for

```
Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(vImg, rImg);
```

> undefined reference to `cv::Stitcher::stitch(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)'

Please help me in fixing this error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you linked the `opencv_stitching` module of opencv?

Comment: I included      #include <opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp>

Comment: I'm talking about the linker flags. Add `-lopencv_core` to the compiler command, if using `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: yeah thank you sgarizvi. It worked after including.Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I meant `-lopencv_stitching`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates the compiler has a *declaration* for these functions but not a *definition*. Try checking your linker flags.